# Data Frame not Loading all the rows from .dat file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on Pandas Data Frames  in Jupyter NoteBook.I am tring to read a .dat file in to Data Frames.
All the rows in the file are not showing when I try to read .

This is my code
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import datetime as dt

df_Heart = pd.read_csv('C:\MyFolder\BigData\heart.dat', header=None)
print(df_Heart)

out of 270 rows only 10 rows(first five  and last five)

Comment: You are reading it like a plain csv file. Are you sure this is a legal csv file, that just misleadingly has a "dat" suffix?

Comment: yes. This is a legal file.Do I need to convert it?

Comment: I have changed the file format to csv. still I am facing the same issue and  all columns are not dispalyed  in a single row.